# Viewbag doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to do this:

```
var NewViewResult = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error", ViewBag.error = "Error Here" };
```

I got these two errors

- Invalid initializer member declarator
- The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

That is my code:

```
public override void OnException(System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled) return;

    string actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    Type controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
    var method = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName);
    var returnType = method.ReturnType;

    if (returnType.Equals(typeof(JsonResult))) if (filterContext.Exception is CustomException) filterContext.Result = new JsonResult() { Data = ((CustomException)filterContext.Exception).Type }; else filterContext.Result = new JsonResult() { Data = OurExceptionType.GeneralException };

    else if (returnType.Equals(typeof(ActionResult)) || (returnType).IsSubclassOf(typeof(ActionResult)))  filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" ViewBag.error="SomeError" }; 


    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

Comment: no it is in CustomExceptionAttribute in
public override void OnException(System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext filterContext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewBag is a dynamic property you cannot pass it like this in a ViewResult.

Set value in ViewBag like this:

```
var NewViewResult = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" }; 

ViewBag.error = "Error Message";
```

and In View, you can simply access it without passing in the `ViewResult`:

```
<span>@ViewBag.error</span>
```

and if you really want to pass it in ViewResult,then don't use `ViewBag`, do like this:

```
var NewViewResult = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
```

Comment: but, how can I pass it?

Comment: you need to set a value in a key with ViewBag like ViewBag.error="some text" and it will be availble in view without doing anyting

Comment: I set some text to error and got the same error,
I tried that
var NewViewResult = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error", Error = "Error Here" };
with this error
does not contain a definition for 'Error'

Comment: In ViewResult class you dont Error field check it

Comment: or do one thing return only ViewName in ViewResult and set error text in ViewBag the way i have shown in asnwer and access it in view from ViewBag

Comment: and also post the complete onException event code so that it is clear to poeple what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks Ehsan I inserted my code, but i need to ask, why I can't pass dynamic viewbag to ViewResult object??

Comment: ViewResult is built in class i google about it, it has specific properties and in general as well viewbag cannot be passed like this in methods or classes, becuase its datatype is made on runtime thats why

Comment: ViewBag is desiged to put some useful data and accessible at rendering view only

Comment: But it is allowed to pass dynamic data type through functions and it can be caught as return type it is easy and doable